# PHP - Replacing ereg with preg

Tags: php, regex, pcre, posix-ere

I'm trying to remove some deprecated code from a site.
Can anyone tell me the preg equivalent of

```
ereg_replace("<b>","<strong>",$content);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be no need for regular expressions at all.

a simple [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) would do:

```
$cleaned = str_replace  ('<b>', '<strong>', $unCleaned);
```

If you need more complicated replacements, for example checking the attributes, you could do:

```
$cleaned = preg_replace('/<b(\s[^>]*)?>/', '<strong\\1>', $unCleaned);
```

But this is by no means perfect; something like `<div title="foo->bar"></div>` would break the regular expression.

Comment: Your current expression will replace any tag starting with `b` (like `base`, `body` or `br`), not just `b` tags. You should use `/<b(\s[^>]*)?>/`

Answer (score 3):

A PCRE equivalent to your ERE regular expression would be:

```
preg_match("/<b>/", "<strong>", $content)
```

But as Jacco already noted you don’t need a regular expression at all as you want to replace a constant value.